Missing questions when using the Active filter on main page
I have observed this behavior more than once recently and I was curious if it was a bug, or just some feature I was not aware of.
Today, I saw via the Featured post the Revisiting the voting requirements test question, opened the link, read some of it, then closed it. Later, I tried to access it via the main page of MSO, but to my surprise, the question isn't visible in the Home section, using the Active questions filter.

However, if I go in the Questions section, and filter on Active questions, I can see the question:

What kind of magic and/or invisible filtering options am I missing here? What's the difference between "Home --> Active", and "Questions --> Active"?

See: answer to: "Meta sites' front pages should not hide questions with very low scores", which says that posts with -8 or less are hidden from the home page of all meta sites.

@Makyen Oh that explains it, thanks for your help. I quickly searched before posting, but didn't use the right keywords, my bad. The question begs to be asked though, should this be changed, seems to me that this is rather too important to be hidden.

Point of interest, the same rule applies on main sites, except the threshold is -4, not -8.

Related over on MSE: Hiding downvoted questions silences important discussions on Meta

"What kind of magic and/or invisible filtering options am I missing here?" - the exact opposite. The questions page has no filters :) Which is why it is the only one I use on meta. The active questions are not very useful to me either, generally that just pops up questions from a decade ago because someone fixed a typo in it somewhere. I get tricked by interesting looking questions too often that way.
